# Creating a bash script to change file names to lower case

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that convert all file names to lowercase, but I have a problem because it does not work for one case.

When you have your `file1` and `FILE1`, and you will use it on the `FILE1` it will replace letters file1.

```
#!/bin/bash

testFILE=""
FLAG="1"

for FILE in * 
do
testFILE=`echo FILE | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`

    for FILE2 in *
    do
        if [  `echo $testFILE` = `echo $FILE2` ]
        then
        FLAG="0"
        fi
    done


    if [ $FLAG =  "1" ]
    then
    mv $FILE `echo $FILE | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    fi

FLAG="1"

done
```

Comment: You can use `mv -i` to prompt before overwriting, and/or use `if [[ -e "$testFILE" ]]; then ...` to check if the file already exists.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like

```
testFILE=`echo FILE | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
```

should be

```
testFILE=`echo "$FILE" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
```

Re-writing your script to fix some other minor things

```
#!/bin/bash

testFILE=
FLAG=1

for FILE in *; do
  testFILE=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$FILE")

  for FILE2 in *; do
    if [  "$testFILE" = "$FILE2" ]; then
      FLAG=0
    fi
  done

  if [ $FLAG -eq  1 ]; then
    mv -- "$FILE" "$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$FILE")"
  fi

  FLAG=1
done
```

- Quote variables to prevent word-splitting (`"$FILE"` instead of `$FILE`)
- Generally preferable to use `$()` instead of tildes
- Don't use string comparison where you don't have to
- Use `--` to delimit arguments in commands that accept it (in order to prevent files like `-file` from being treated as options)
- By convention, you should really only use capital variable names for environment variables, though I kept them in above.
- Pipes vs here strings (`<<<`) doesn't matter so much here, but `<<<` is slightly faster and generally safer.

Though more simply, I think you want

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
  testFile=$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$file")
  [ -e "$testFile" ] || mv -- "$file" "$testFile"
done
```

Or on most modern `mv` implementations (not technically posix)

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
  mv -n -- "$file" "$(tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$file")"
done
```

From the `man` page

```
-n, --no-clobber
       do not overwrite an existing file
```

Comment: ...or even simpler: `"${file,,}"`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, but only in bash 4+

Answer (score 1):

Below script :

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while read -d '' filename
do 
   if [ -e ${filename,,} ]
   then
    mv --backup ${filename} ${filename,,} 2>/dev/null 
        # create a backup of the desination only if the destination already exist
        # suppressing the error caused by moving the file to itself
   else 
    mv ${filename} ${filename,,}
   fi
done
```

may do the job for you.

**Advantages of this script**

1. It will parse files containing newlines.
2. It avoids a prompt by doing selective backup destination that already exists.